# Combining SQL Select statements into a single Select Statement? (Simplification.)

Tags: sql, select, count

I'm kind of a noob when it comes to SQL, so forgive me if this obvious.
I wanted to find duplicates of the Customer field, and the FULL records that had them.

**Note:** *I am using MS SQL Server 2005.*

I tried to implement the it as a single SQL Select statement before I came up with the following:

```
SELECT ModTab.* from modTab
    WHERE Customer IN (SELECT Customer
            FROM    ModTab
            GROUP BY Customer
            HAVING COUNT(Customer) > 1
        )
    ORDER BY Customer
```

Originally I tried a dozen differnt variations on something like:

```
SELECT ModTab.*
FROM    ModTab
GROUP BY Customer,<ALL other fields...>
HAVING COUNT(Customer) > 1
```

Is there something like the second approach which accomplishes the same thing?
(Plus the Group by clause seems someone pointless to me?  I'm not realclear on why it's needed or used.)

Comment: Since you are new at SQL, the first things you should learn is that select * is an anti-pattern that you shuld not be using in production code.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If using Sql server 2008 then try CTE

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select modTab.*
from ModTab
join (
  select Customer, count(*) 
  from Modtab 
  group by Customer
) B on B.Customer = ModTab.Customer
order b Customer
```

I believe this also now explains the need for the group by.

Answer (score 0):

If using an RDBMS (such as SQLServer) that supports analytic functions, try:

```
select * from
(select m.*, count(*) over (partition by customer) cnt
 from Modtab m) ilq
where cnt > 1
```

Otherwise, try:

```
select m.*
from Modtab m
where exists
(select 1
 from Modtab l
 where m.customer = l.customer and m.id <> l.id)
```

(Replace `id` with the suitable primary key field for Modtab.)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH    numbered
AS ( SELECT   *, row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY customer  ) AS nr FROM ModTab)
Select * from numbered WHERE   nr >1
```

Comment: This works: "WITH numbered AS ( SELECT row_number() over (Order by Customer) AS uid, (count(*) over (partition by Customer)) AS cnt, * FROM ModTab ) Select * from numbered WHERE cnt >1" BUT WHY can't I just put the cnt>1 on the inner Select statement?!?!?!?!